# Does the Jenkins update affect current plug-in?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm about to migrate Jenkins from version `2.190.3` to `2.204.6`. As I know, I need to update installed plugins manually after updating Jenkins. I've got two questions here.

1. Does the Jenkins update affect current plug-in? or does it work the same as before updating the plug-in?
2. How can I find the expected side effects when I proceed with the update? Are there any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Does the Jenkins update affect current plug-in? or does it work the same as before updating the plug-in?

- **Ans:** Jenkins only update jenkin-core, it doesn't update current plugin. However, some plugin may be broken after update Jenkins-core due to incompatibility to new Jenkins-core

2. How can I find the expected side effects when I proceed with the update? Are there any tips?

- **Ans:** we can not to be sure any expected side effect. So, when you proceed with the update, just go to "Manage Jenkins", it will shows you broken plugins that need to be upgraded to new version.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to update all your plugins to "latest (compatible)" as possible, then upgrade Jenkins, the upgrade your plugins again.

Read the [Upgrade Guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/) ans [Change log](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/). 2.204.6 is still very old. Recommend to 2.263.4 first as 2.277.x will [break many plugins](https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=20741) as a result of tables to divs migration.

Plugins are/must be upgraded separately from the app. Existing plugins may no longer be compatible, typically for security issues or a core plugins being decoupled. Some plugins may only work with newer core versions.

You should take a copy of your instance & config, update that and validate, then move to your real system.